# Unable to Improve Draft

Tags: discussion, documentation, error-message

A few days ago I added an example to a new requested topic `machinelearning` in Documentation.  I submitted my example and the draft was rejected.  Ultimately I agreed with the feedback and went to update my example.

Yesterday I went it to make some changes and saved a new draft.  I went back to it today and wanted to finish up my new draft and submit for a second review, but now when I click "Improve Draft" I get an error.

[image: Error Page]

Am I unable to edit the draft because the topic can no longer be responded to?  I was able to edit it earlier when it said the topic cannot be responded to.  The version of my example shown now is the very first version so I'm not sure if my newest draft was even saved.

I'll fully admit that I'm not sure if I'm doing this right and this may be 100% user error, but I'd be very grateful to anyone who could explain what's going on.  I'll be happy to add more details as needed.